# SQL - Find last 3 Occurrences based on date field and label as value C1, C2 and C3

Tags: sql-server

I could use your help with this one.
I am trying to find last 3 Occurrences based on date field and label as value C1, C2 and C3 in a new column where C1 is the most recent, C2 is the 2nd most recent and C3 is the 3rd most recent.

My current table

| CYCKEY | LAST_MOD |
| --- | --- |
| KER123 | 09/03/2020 |
| KER123 | 09/01/2020 |
| KER123 | 08/15/2020 |
| KER123 | 07/15/2020 |
| KER125 | 09/02/2020 |
| KER125 | 08/10/2020 |
| KER125 | 07/15/2020 |
| KER125 | 06/10/2020 |

My desired Table

| CYCKEY | LAST_MOD | NEW_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KER123 | 09/03/2020 | C1 |
| KER123 | 09/01/2020 | C2 |
| KER123 | 08/15/2020 | C3 |
| KER123 | 07/15/2020 |  |
| KER125 | 09/02/2020 | C1 |
| KER125 | 08/10/2020 | C2 |
| KER125 | 07/15/2020 | C3 |
| KER125 | 06/10/2020 |  |

I do not care to label records after the 3rd occurrence or they could be labeled 'N/A.' It doesn't matter really.
Any help or ideas on how to approach this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use-case for the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) aggregate.

First, we'll create a temporary table to hold some data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

SELECT v.n, v.d
INTO #t
FROM (
    VALUES 
          ('a', '2021-01-01T00:00:01')
        , ('a', '2021-01-01T00:00:02')
        , ('a', '2021-01-01T00:00:03')
        , ('a', '2021-01-01T00:00:04')
        , ('a', '2021-01-01T00:00:05')
        , ('b', '2021-01-02T00:00:06')
        , ('b', '2021-01-02T00:00:07')
        , ('b', '2021-01-02T00:00:08')
        , ('b', '2021-01-02T00:00:09')
        , ('b', '2021-01-02T00:00:10')
        , ('b', '2021-01-02T00:00:11')
) v(n, d)
```

Here's the query using `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the desired results:

```
;WITH with_row_numbers AS
(
    SELECT *
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n ORDER BY d DESC)
    FROM #t src
)
SELECT with_row_numbers.n
    , with_row_numbers.d
    , new_col = 'C' + CONVERT(char(1), 4 - with_row_numbers.rn)
FROM with_row_numbers
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY with_row_numbers.n, with_row_numbers.d;
```

The output looks like:

| n | d | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-01-01T00:00:03 | C1 |
| a | 2021-01-01T00:00:04 | C2 |
| a | 2021-01-01T00:00:05 | C3 |
| b | 2021-01-02T00:00:09 | C1 |
| b | 2021-01-02T00:00:10 | C2 |
| b | 2021-01-02T00:00:11 | C3 |

The `ROW_NUMBER()` aggregate is used to generate row numbers that are partitioned by one or more columns, and ordered by one or more columns.  In this case, I'm choosing to order using the `DESC` keyword to get the highest-numbered rows first.  Then in the main query, I'm using a `WHERE` clause to only choose rows with row-numbers from 1 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to get your c-values for C and also find the last date for every cyckey

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tabl2
>     ([CYCKEY] varchar(6), [LAST_MOD] datetime)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tabl2
>     ([CYCKEY], [LAST_MOD])
> VALUES
>     ('KER123', '2020-09-03 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER123', '2020-09-01 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER123', '2020-08-15 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER123', '2020-07-15 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER123', '2020-01-15 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER123', '2020-02-15 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER125', '2020-09-02 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER125', '2020-08-10 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER125', '2020-07-15 02:00:00'),
>     ('KER125', '2020-06-10 02:00:00')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT [CYCKEY], [LAST_MOD]
> ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CYCKEY] ORDER BY [LAST_MOD] DESC) rnDesc
> From tabl2)
> SELECT [CYCKEY], [LAST_MOD], CASE WHEN rnDesc = 1 
> Then '' 
> WHEN rnDesc > 1 AND rnDesc < 5 THEN  CONCAT('C' , [rnDesc] - 1) 
> ELSE '' END NEW_COL 
> FROm CTE
> ORDER BY [CYCKEY],[LAST_MOD]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CYCKEY | LAST_MOD                | NEW_COL
> :----- | :---------------------- | :------
> KER123 | 2020-01-15 02:00:00.000 |        
> KER123 | 2020-02-15 02:00:00.000 |        
> KER123 | 2020-07-15 02:00:00.000 | C3     
> KER123 | 2020-08-15 02:00:00.000 | C2     
> KER123 | 2020-09-01 02:00:00.000 | C1     
> KER123 | 2020-09-03 02:00:00.000 |        
> KER125 | 2020-06-10 02:00:00.000 | C3     
> KER125 | 2020-07-15 02:00:00.000 | C2     
> KER125 | 2020-08-10 02:00:00.000 | C1     
> KER125 | 2020-09-02 02:00:00.000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb4ecb684c531a702a2ce1669a4b0d26)*